# How can I change the Forecolor of the Textbox on the OnClick?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have 2 textboxes which has default values in forecolor:#999999. If I click on the textbox, the default value should clear and the forecolor should change to black. I mean, like watermarking. But I am not using any Ajax. need help...please...

Answer (score 1):

You should use the *onfocus* and *onblur* events, rather than relying on click events.  This way, it will work for keyboard users tabbing through the document.

```
var myInput = document.getElementById("myInput");
myInput.onfocus = function () {
    if (this.value == "Default Input Value") {
        this.value = "";
        this.style.color = "#000";
    }
}
myInput.onblur = function () {
    if (this.value == "") {
        this.value = "Default Input Value";
        this.style.color = "#999";
    }
}
```

See it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f9DCs/).